# I have x and y coordinates in my map. The coordinates of x are different marker and have a bevel. Also in y. How can I do it in the following code?

Tags: php, maps, marker

I have x and y coordinates in my map. The coordinates of x are different marker and have a bevel. Also in y.
How can I do it in the following code?

```
<div id="map"></div>
<div id="right-panel">
<p>Total Distance: <span id="total"></span></p>
</div>
<script>
function initMap() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 4,
        center: {lat: -24.345, lng: 134.46}  // Australia.
    });

    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
    var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
        draggable: false,//marker hareketi sabit
        map: map,
        panel: document.getElementById('right-panel')
    });

    directionsDisplay.addListener('directions_changed', function() {
        computeTotalDistance(directionsDisplay.getDirections());
    });

    displayRoute('Malatya', 'Malatya', directionsService,
        directionsDisplay);
 }

function displayRoute(origin, destination, service, display) {
    service.route({
        origin: origin,
        destination: destination,
        waypoints: [<?=$directions?>],
        travelMode: 'DRIVING',
        avoidTolls: true
    }, function(response, status) {
        if (status === 'OK') {
            display.setDirections(response);
        } else {
            alert('Could not display directions due to: ' + status);
        }
    });
 }

function computeTotalDistance(result) {
    var total = 0;
    var myroute = result.routes[0];
    for (var i = 0; i < myroute.legs.length; i++) {
        total += myroute.legs[i].distance.value;
    }
    total = total / 1000;
    document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = total + ' km';
}
```

Comment: i want different markers and titles for selected coordinates

Comment: Edit your question and include the text from your comment in there so that anyone who's coming to assist can find everything relevant to the question in one place.